# Reference not found in xaml but present in xaml.cs

Tags: c#, .net

I have the same problem as here

[Assembly reference not found in XAML, but code compiles when referenced in xaml.cs class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885371/assembly-reference-not-found-in-xaml-but-code-compiles-when-referenced-in-xaml)

but I don't understand what he means in answer: "Adding the solution itself to the reference path of the assembly solves the problem! ".

I downloaded Example project too from WPF.MDI project web page and it works fine. I use VS 2012 and.Net 4.5 on Win 8. Can someone explain me in details what i have to do in VS? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here, that might help you maybe : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6taasyc6(v=vs.80).aspx

Hope you'll fix your problem !

Comment: I downloaded source code and compiled dll and than added it to my project and now works. :)

Answer (score -2):

For me, the problem came from "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer" on each dll. I just unblocked it. :-)