# MDI in WPF .Net Project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mdi

I have downloaded the MDI Library from the following link

https://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/ and then it placed it in bin folder of WPF project and write the

```
xmlns:mdi="clr-namespace:WPF.MDI;assembly=WPF.MDI"
```

in xaml.cs 
but when i write

```
<mdi:MdiContainer></mdi:MdiContainer>
```

I faced the error

> the mdiContainer doesnot exists in current namespace
>   xmlns:mdi="clr-namespace:WPF.MDI;assembly=WPF.MDI

Can anyone tell me what is the exact problem?

Comment: Have you added reference to the wpfmdi dll?

Comment: yes i have added then reference

Comment: sometimes an exception is thrown in XAML that isn't relevant any more , ignore it and try to run it any ways

Comment: i cant view the layout, Facing error of Invalid MarkUP

Comment: mdi is not working in xaml

Comment: It isn't error, it is warning. I don't know why, but WPF.MDI doesn't visible in the designer, but if you run your application you will see that it works correct.

Comment: but then i could not be able to view my design :| how to get rid of this?

Comment: I see it, the XAML designer is a bit helpless at finding the DLL.  Remove the assembly reference, copy the DLL into your project directory, add the reference back.  Don't forget to add it to source control.

Comment: source control means?

Comment: Try not to be helpless as well.  You can just google it, take the first hit.

Comment: tried but same error

Comment: I had the same problem Check this answer: [Adding dll reference WPF MDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885371/assembly-reference-not-found-in-xaml-but-code-compiles-when-referenced-in-xaml)

Answer (score 0):

First download the solution for the WPF Multiple Document Interface (MDI) from CodePlex then build that solution and copy the output WPF.MDI.dll from the Debug folder which is inside the bin folder then reference it in your project instead of the library you downloaded first from CodePlex and it will work out. At least it worked for me :)